# Django : cannot find model when inserting values to model from html form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to insert values to sqlite database using basic django forms.

These are my Settings

**Models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):

   def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse ('books:detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

   def __str__(self):

    return self.name+ '-'+self.author
   name         = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   author       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   genere       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   year         = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   image        = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/',null=True,blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Book

SOME_CHOICES = (
        ('Science fiction','Science fiction'),
        ('Psychology','Psychology'),
        ('Philosophy','Philosophy'),
        ('Novel','Novel'),
        ('Poetry','Poetry'),

   )

class BookForm(forms.Form):

   name          = forms.CharField()
   author    = forms.CharField()
   genere       = forms.CharField(label='Text',widget= forms .Select
                                                  (choices=SOME_CHOICES))
   year         = forms.CharField()
   book_image   = forms.ImageField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from books.forms import BookForm
from django import forms
from books.models import Book
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Book
from django.views.generic  import (ListView,CreateView,UpdateView,DeleteView,TemplateView)
from django.template import loader
from django.http  import Http404
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

    def Book_Create_View(request):
        form=BookForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            book_obj=models.Book()
            book_obj.name = request.POST.get("name")
            book_obj.author = request.POST.get("author")
            book_obj.genere = request.POST.get("genere")
            book_obj.year = request.POST.get("year")
            book_obj.image = request.FILES
            book_obj.save()
            return redirect('books:index')
        else:
            form = BookForm()
            template ='books/book_form.html'
            return render(request,template,{'form':form})
```

**book_form.html**

```
{% extends 'books/base.html'%}
 {%block content%}


                   <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                         {{form}}

                        <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sucess">Submit
                                </button>
                            </div>
                      </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views
from books.views import ListView,BookCategoryListView,BookCreateView,UpdateView,Book_Create_View
from books import views
app_name='books'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
    # url(r'bookadd/$',views.book_create_view,name='add'),
    # url(r'^add',views.book_create_view,name='book_add') ,
    # url(r'^create/$',views.BookCreateView.as_view(),name='create') ,
    url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.BookUpdateView.as_view(),name='update'),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.BookDeleteView.as_view(),name='delete'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>\w+)$',views.BookCategoryListView.as_view()) ,
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.DetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
    url(r'^create/$',views.Book_Create_View,name='create') 
]
```

But its returning an error

```
name 'models' is not defined
```

The Urls.py looks fine to me as I can insert using model forms and its fine but here its returning the error

how to Solve this and insert the values using the form?

Comment: Note that you should never ever ever (I stress this, it's really important) assign model variables to your user input directly! `book_obj.author = request.POST.get("author")` is very dangerous! You're saving unprocessed input into your database which could allow anyone to inject malicious code into your app, both SQL injection and XSS injection. Always use the form's `cleaned_data` dictionary.

Comment: @dirkgroten , sure....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling Book from models. You should just call Book, since its already imported.
Change your code to this:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        book_obj=Book()
        book_obj.name = request.POST.get("name")
        book_obj.author = request.POST.get("author")
        book_obj.genere = request.POST.get("genere")
        book_obj.year = request.POST.get("year")
        book_obj.save()
        return redirect('books:index')
```

Comment: another  error  `MultiValueDict' object has no attribute '_committed'`

Comment: remove this line `book_obj.image = request.FILES` and try again

Comment: the thing now is that you need to handle `request.FILES` before assigning it directly to the image

Comment: that's a different question and you should first research how to upload files with django. The official documentation has a simple example that you can almost copy&paste exactly into your code and there are plenty of questions on StackOverflow that show you how to do it.

Comment: @dirkgroten , i wonder this method is working while using model form and its doing the job. ..

Comment: @Walucas . error never mentions anything about image.

Comment: request.FILES, you need to iterate over the files first... you are assigning a dict to a image field

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/), it shows examples for both the ModelForm case and the plain form case. You can't assign `request.FILES` directly to a `FileField` that's not how it works.

Comment: And yes, using a `ModelForm` would make your life much simpler. You can then just save the form without having to assign all properties of a `Book` yourself.

Comment: While the answer given resolves the issue, it's a bad answer because 1) the code won't work and 2) it is dangerous code that should never be written this way.

Comment: @Walucas , i solve it using `file = request.FILES['book_image']` .. its okay now